# Not getting service worker with create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker

lately, I have create two react application and in both of them the service worker is not present instead a new file is generated i.e 'reportWebVitals.js'.
Here is my folder structure of src after creating new app.
[image: File Structure]

Also, if we check on running the app, the browser says that 'No matching service worker detected'

Comment: Yes, that's correct. CRA no longer has a web worker out of the box. It's a separate template now: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks @jonrsharpe
So, CRA does not give support for service worker directly with default installation command as developer may not be making the application as PWA. So, they decided to keep it optional. Like me, if you anyone else want to install service worker while creating a new app, Prefer:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa
```

instead of default `npx create-react-app my-app`.
[image]
Hence, for more yo can refer to https://create-react-app.dev/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app/

Answer (score 26):

If you have already existing project and you want to migrate to the new versions of CRA, you can follow this steps:

**1 Create somewhere on your computer a new CRA with the service worker template:**

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa
```

**2 Copy the service-worker.js from the new created app into your src directory**

**3 Copy the "workbox-*" dependencies from the package.json into your package.json dependencies**

**4 (Optional) If you want web-vitals, copy the web-vitals dependency from package.json into your package.json**

and don't forget to run again 'yarn install' or 'npm install'

Thats it

Comment: Is this all I have to do? Do I not have to call on `registerServiceWorker()` or something?

Comment: @AliBdeir If you are migrating from CRA 3 with existing Service Worker to CRA 4, I assume that you call already your `registerServiceWorker()` in the  index.js. If you start a new project or you want to migrate old with no existing service worker, then just call `npx create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa` and use/copy the template

Comment: youre also going to want to copy over the `serviceWorkerRegistration.js` file and change the import statement and function call in index.js to reference this new file

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround if you have an already exiting react project without the template:

Go to your `index.html` file in `public` folder and add a `<script>` tag there and you can register the `service worker` from your `<script>` tag in `index.html` using:

```
if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register("/serviceworker.js")
        .then(e => console.log("Service worker registered", e))
        .catch(e => console.log("service worker failed", e));
}
```

this way you can cache your public icon files and images.

Comment: Thank you for sharing a solution that does not require creating a new project

Answer (score 1):

run this command "npx create-react-app your-app-name --template cra-template-pwa" instead of "npx create-react-app your-app-name"

Comment: Duplicate of the previous answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/69001897/14005627

Answer (score 1):

you need to run this command

```
npx create-react-app your-app-name --template cra-template-pwa
```

instead of

```
npx create-react-app your-app-name
```

Answer (score -1):

When migrating for a full-stack app make sure you do all the steps from "bukso" plus:

- Add your serviceWorkerRegistration.js file to the root of src, just like the service-worker.js
- Build your full-stack app, install your static server with "npm install --global serve"
- Go to the client-side directory and run your server on the statically created build folder with "serve -s build"