# Serviceworker file not found

Tags: reactjs, redux

I don't have service worker file in my app and I have completed it 70%.

[image: screenshot]

so what should i do to import it ?

Comment: Have you tried this method?
[not-getting-service-worker-with-create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65060150/not-getting-service-worker-with-create-react-app)

Comment: I didn't understand that

Comment: @TaranpreetSingh follow these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67018656/16441330 and see what happens